# Is a .photography domain currently a good choice for a portfolio website?

Tags: web, portfolio, internet

I've had a domain name in my mind that I've wanted for my photography for a while now, but it's been taken for all popular TLDs (.com, .net, et c.) for a long time. I don't want it so bad that I would consider asking the owners of it if they would be willing to sell the domains to me. Instead, I've thought about getting the domain with the new `.photography` TLD instead (it's not taken yet, I've checked).

I want to know if this domain is a good choice for a personal photography/portfolio website that might potentially be used to attract customers. I don't want to start a discussion about SEO (which is why i post this question here and not on webmasters.SE), I know the new TLDs are at a disadvantage in this regard as of yet. Instead, I want to know how such a domain would be perceived, whether it would be regarded as too gimmicky or not taken seriously. If you know about any other pitfalls with new TLDs, I'd like to know about them as well (for example, I currently use a `.world` domain and had people fail to write me emails because they kept putting `.world.com` in the adress ...) Also, if any of you already use a `.photography` domain and can share their experiences with it, that would be great.

I live in Germany, in case that's relevant. The domain I want is taken for `.de` as well. However, it's just a small personal sites, I don't think I would be having any trouble considering SEO or trademarks in this regard.

Comment: Throwing more gas on the fire, don't forget about `.photo`, `.photos`, `.pictures`, `.pics` (and maybe even `.camera`) to round out your brand. All owned by different gTLD registrars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think the question, "is `.photography` currently a good choice for a portfolio website" is the right question to ask. In my opinion, you should be asking if `MoritzLost.photography` (as an example) is the right brand *for you*.

If the brand you present (content and portfolio) is good, then it will work for you. If your brand is mediocre, then it probably won't help or hurt you. The TLD doesn't make or break you; you make your domain work because of *content*, regardless of TLD.

Put it this way: if you saw RyanBrenizer.photography (as an alternative to RyanBrenizer.com), and knowing his brand, would you think the `.photography` TLD helps or hurts his brand? I don't think so. His brand is distinctive. Adding `.photography` just solidifies him as *the* Ryan Brenizer in my mind.

Similarly, I'm completely baffled why Jared Polin doesn't heavily brand `froknows.photo`. He already has a recognizeable brand in `froknowsphoto.com`; seems to me `froknows.photo` would be a logical extension.

Comment: I can't imaging Jared just stoping to "Fro knows photo....." (nothing!). I love how he says "dot com" after a pause! So yeah, maybe this is another good example on your branding argument.

Answer (score 3):

When did you type a complete web address in a browser the last time?
(I can't remember)

Typically, people google addresses or have a link from somewhere.
Therefore, it matters little how the real address is made up - it should have some recognizability and sound 'real' (so efoth.fkfhry.kh might *not* be a great choice), but otherwise, whatever works and is available.

Comment: all the time. last time was just a few minutes ago bringing up a stack exchange site. You can bet if somebody gives me a business card or resume or other item with a URL on it, I'm going to type that in rather than type in something similar but different and rely on google to find something for me that I already know how to find.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I own both [myname].photography and [myname]photography.com so that if people don't remember correctly—or aren't used to the new tlds—they'll still be able to find me.